# Asp .Net & Angular 11 - SignalR 404 Error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a .NET 4.7 application that runs ASP.NET Core 2.2 and I'm trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR version 1.0.1 with Angular 11.
It's currently not possible to target .NET Core.
SignalR is configured in the Startup.cs like this:

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
});
```

and `services.AddSignalR();`

The Angular code:

```
initHub() {
    this._hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.baseUrl + '/chathub')
        .build();
    this._hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => {
        console.log('Hub connection started');
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log('Error while establishing connection');
    });
}
```

The `start()` call fails because it tries to reach /chathub/negotiate and gets a 404 response. In Angular I'm using `"@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0-rc1-update1"`,

Any ideas what might be the problem?
BTW I'm using an Angular proxy to redirect all requests to port 8990, because of CORS. Maybe this has something to do with the problem.

Comment: You should use [`@microsoft/signalr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) on the angular side for SignalR.

Comment: I just tried @microsoft/signalr, but it tries to call the same endpoint and gets the same error.